# Maximum call stack size exceeded Datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, datatables

I'm having an issue using jQuery Datatables plugin, I use an AJAX call to get data from my database, the problem is when my data contains more than 50k rows, when this happen I get the following error message:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>   at jQuery.fn.init.push ()
>   at Function.Sizzle [as find] (jquery-3.1.1.js:825)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.find (jquery-3.1.1.js:2921)
>   at HTMLTableElement. (datatables.min.js:109)
>   at Function.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:368)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.each (jquery-3.1.1.js:157)
>   at jQuery.fn.init.m [as dataTable] (datatables.min.js:102)
>   at reportes.html:282
>   at Object.success (CallWebMethod.js:258)
>   at fire (jquery-3.1.1.js:3305)

For the drawing of my table I use something like this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < myAjaxResult.length; i++) {
   htmlVal += '<tr><td>' + myAjaxResult[i].ColumnName + '</td></tr>';
}
$('#TablaId').dataTable().fnDestroy();
$('#TablaBodyId').html("");
$('#TablaBodyId').append(htmlVal);
$('#TablaId).dataTable({
    aLengthMenu: [
       [10, 25, 50, 100, -1],
       [10, 25, 50, 100, "All"]
    ],
    "bDestroy": true,
    iDisplayLength: 25
});
```

When my database data is less than 50k everything works fine, even when I remove the lines that contains .dataTable() and draw the table in pure HTML works fine with more than 50k rows. The only problem is when I'm adding .dataTable()

**EDIT: Works perfect in Firefox, at the moment the problem is only with Chrome**

What could be the problem?

Comment: Too much data: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RangeError

Split up your Ajax result and iterate, perhaps half it upon iterating through half of the array indexes (n divided by 2). Also use document fragment as this performs better in the DOM: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/createDocumentFragment

Comment: @jburtondev But doesn't matter that works without problem and with the same data? Because when I don't use any dataTable() method my table is showed properly and without error message

Comment: Ah I see. Have you tried: `var table = $('#TablaId').dataTable()` then to destroy it: `table.destroy();` ?

Comment: @jburtondev I get the same message